# How to use main actvitiy floating action button from fragments in single activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I'm using BottomAppbar with floating action button  in single activity.The Fab has different responsibility in different fragment.

- HomeFragment -> adds new item
- AddProblemFragment ->saves item(also icon changes)
- DetailsFragment -> adds  items to selected collections(also icon changes)

I have tried to use listener between activity and fragments. Icon and position changes perfectly but I couldn't handle calling methods that in fragments when clicked.

To solve clicking problem I'm getting fab reference from activity with

`fab = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab)` in **each fragment** (in onViewCreated).

So, problem is after orientation changes gives
`java.lang.NullPointerException: requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab) must not be null`

Is there way to avoid getting this error after orientation changes? or Which lifecycle should choose to initialize fab?

Is it possible to initialize fab in BaseFragment and use it because almost each fragment have fab?

The Code Snippets:

```
//Each fragment same approach

private lateinit var fab:FloatingActionButton

override fun onViewCreated(view:View,savedInstanceState:Bundle?){

fab = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_btn_add)
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_related_icon)
fab.setOnClickListener {
    //calls method
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using the deprecated `<fragment>` tag in your activity's layout XML. Is there a reason you aren't using `FragmentContainerView`, which does not suffer from this problem?

Comment: It's worked. I replaced it with FragmentContainerView. <fragment> was causing this  problem.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create an interface for you fab click listener for Example:

```
interface FabClickCallback {
    
   void onFabClick()

}
```

and on your activity,

You Need create an instance from this Callback

```
private FabClickCallback fabCallback;
```

and you want create new method inside your Activity called for Example:

```
public void handleFabClickListener(FabClickCallback callback){
   // TODO Here put callback
   this.fabCallback = callback;
}
```

and you want trigger this callback when user click on Fab Button like This:

```
fab.setOnClickListener ( view -> {
  if (this.fabCallback != null ) {
     this.fabCallback.onFabClick();
   }
});
```

finally on Each Fragment you want handle Fab Click you want call this function and pass your actual fab click code :

```
 ((YourActivity) requireActivity()).handleFabClickListener(this);
```

and your fragment must **implements FabClickCallback** interface

Comment: I would not suggest this as it 1) basically puts your in a circular loop and 2) puts an explicit dependency on the parent Activity within each Fragment. To remain decoupled and reusable, Fragments should have no knowledge of their owning Activity. Refer to: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: I agree with you man. 
but this solutions  is work as simple solution  and this work will work even his not used `fragment-ktx` 

so to optimize this solution he can set FabCallback = null  onStop inside fragment